# size of a node in linked list

Tags: c++, malloc, sizeof

**Program:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
struct node 
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

int main() 
{
    struct node* head = NULL;
    head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
    cout<<sizeof(struct node)<<"\n"<<sizeof(head)<<"\n"<<sizeof(int);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
8
4
4
```

1. Why is `sizeof(struct node)` different than `sizeof(head)` ?
   Wouldn't have malloc allocated 8 bytes ?
2. Since `sizeof(head)` is
   same as `sizeof(int)` , where is `next` stored then ?

Comment: Instead of writing C code in C++, why not use C++? (in other words: prefer `new` over `malloc`, but use smart pointers, automatic storage, and container classes where possible). Also, `struct node { };` makes `node` a typename, so you don't need to repeat the `struct` when using the type.

Comment: `c++ | size of a node in linked list`  sizeof() is a compile time value, therefore your issue has absolutely nothing to do with `malloc` or linked lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`head` is not a node, it is a pointer to a node. So `sizeof(head)` gives you the size of a pointer, which has no relation to the size of the thing it points at. `sizeof(*head)` would give you the size of a node.

Comment: why is sizeof(head) is 4 bytes, why not something else ?

Comment: @g4ur4v: Because that how many bytes it takes to store the address of an object on your implementation.

Comment: @g4ur4v See here:  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c2bdc2772127d2f  The size *can* be "something else", as Benjamin pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is as follows

```
 cout<<sizeof(struct node) // returns the size of struct node 4 bytes for pointer and 4 bytes for int
 sizeof(head) // returns the size of pointer 4 bytes
 sizeof(int); // returns the size of integer 4 bytes
```

Comment: why is sizeof(head) is 4 bytes, why not something else ?

Comment: The size of pointer can be anything 4 bytes or 8 bytes depending on architecture.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` evaluates the size of the *type* of the expression. In this case `head` is a pointer. On a 32 bit machine pointers are 4 bytes, coincidentally integers are also 4 bytes.

To correctly get the size of `head` without the actual type name, `sizeof` is smart enough to figure it out if you de-reference the object.

```
// == sizeof(struct node)
sizeof(*head)
```